# How can i use limit offset pagination for viewsets

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, drf-queryset

Views.py

```
class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ViewSet):   
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
    def list(self,request):
        try:
            country_data = Country.objects.all()
            country_serializer = CountrySerializer(country_data,many=True)
            return Response(            
                data = country_serializer.data,
                content_type='application/json',            
                )
        except Exception as ex:
            return Response(
                data={'error': str(ex)},
                content_type='application/json',
                status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
                )
```

Settings.py
i have added

```
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
```

in my urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter(trailing_slash=False)

router.register(r'country', CountryViewSet, base_name='country')
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

When I try with this URL http://192.168.2.66:8001/v1/voucher/country it is returning all data.

But when I am trying with this URL http://192.168.2.66:8001/v1/voucher/country/?limit=2&offset=2

but it is returning 404 error.
I am new to django.kindly help me :)

Comment: Surely you get 404 because you've set trailing_slash=False but you are using a trailing slash in your URL. This has nothing to do with offsets.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [**`ModelViewSet`**](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset) not `ViewSet`. Also remove your list function it will automatically send response.

```
from rest_framework.pagination import LimitOffsetPagination

class CountryViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """
    A simple ViewSet for viewing and editing country.
    """ 
    queryset = Country.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountrySerializer
    pagination_class = LimitOffsetPagination
```

> The actions provided by the ModelViewSet class are .list(),
>   .retrieve(), .create(), .update(), .partial_update(), and .destroy().

**UPDATE**

In your settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'PAGE_SIZE': 10,
    # 'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination',
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

Alternatively, you can just use `paginate_queryset` and `get_paginated_response`

```
def list(self,request):
    country_data = Country.objects.all()

    page = self.paginate_queryset(country_data)
    if page is not None:
       serializer = self.get_serializer(page, many=True)
       return self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)

    serializer = self.get_serializer(country_data, many=True)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

> **Reference:**
>   [marking-extra-actions-for-routing](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Comment: if i use ModelViewSet, then can i use list(),retrieve(),create(),update(),destroy() options?

Comment: Still i am facing the same. :(

Comment: you need to set `PAGE_SIZE` in your settings.py

Comment: check my update try creating another class of pagination and use that class in viewset.

Comment: @SusajSNair, is that worked? also have look on DanielRoseman comment

Comment: when i try without your custom class and without trailing slash, it is selecting all data..

Comment: How can i get limit, offset  from request side. It cannot be staic values. By using your custom class it is not possible i guess.

Comment: yes, check my update remove custom class and set default `PAGE_SIZE`, also remove trailing slash.

Comment: i have tried with URL 'http://192.168.2.66:8001/v1/voucher/country?limit=3&offset=2'. And removed your custom class , Removed  'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS' But still it is selecting all data :(

Comment: can i look into your code, if you can share it on git, i am also using it in my project and it is working fine

Comment: can you do make `trailing_slash=False` to `True` in urls.py and try fetching it with trailing slash i.e `'https://192.168.2.66:8001/v1/voucher/country/?limit=3&offset=2'`

Comment: Anyway its not working properly. it is selecting all data.Kindly note that by requesting this URL it is mapping to list() method where i have 'country_data = Country.objects.filter(chrDocumentStatus = 'N')' this statement. Kindly help me i can't share it via Github :(

Comment: you can use `self.get_paginated_response(serializer.data)` as make your implementation as it is, read docs http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing

Comment: 'print(self.get_paginated_response(country_serializer.data))'

i am getting ** LimitOffsetPagination object has no attribute count ** error

Comment: But when i am giving {country_data = self.paginate_queryset(country_data)} it is giving proper result .But iwant the next and previous URL with offset and list value.

Comment: where is his own serializer to get custom fields